# Token authentication django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I need a help, im using `django framework` and `django rest framework` on my web service and site, but I have a problem with `CSRF`. The mobile app is trying to send the `CSRF` token but the web service rejects it. I try to use the authentication of rest framework through the url `apitokenauth`, that returns a token but I dont know how use this token on method `authz_required(style @login_required)` and how can i get the user of session?

```
def authz_required(function):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        if not (request.user.is_authenticated()):
            if (request.path == "/") or (request.path == "/authz/") or (request.path == "/authz/login/"):
                return function(request, *args, **kw)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            ...

    return wrapper
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish here.. Can you show example of using `authz_required` decorator on any of your views?